# I'm using pyinstaller to make my python file executable. I am using tkvideo inside the file. I have the mp4 in the same directory. It doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm using **pyinstaller** to turn it to exe. It creates the window when I run it but, no video playing. I have the mp4 in the same directory as the .exe, but still **no** video plays. This all works as a **regular** python file.
Here is the code for the tkvideo:

```py
root = Tk()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    my_label = Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    
    threading.Thread(target=volume).start()
    threading.Thread(target=play).start()
    threading.Thread(target=emergency).start()
    
    player = tkvideo("SHREK/MLG SHREK COMPILATION!.mp4", my_label, loop = 1, size = (1280,720))
    player.play()
    
    def on_closing():
       player.play()
    
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Do I need to put the mp4 in a specific place?

Comment: the file has to be in the same relative directory where the python file is executed, not the executable, or provide the full path

Comment: @Matiiss It is. That's why I'm so confused

Comment: no it is not, otherwise it would work, do you know where the python file is executed? likely somewhere in `%temp%`

Answer (score 0):

For example if your structure is sth like this:

```
some_dir
| executable.exe
| directory
  | file.mp4
```

And you want to open `file.mp4`, then in your python file you need to specify path like this:

```py
import os
import sys

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'directory/file.mp4')
```